# What to use instead of SafeHandle.DangerousGetHandle?

Tags: c#, .net, handle, interopservices, safehandle

I was looking at my SonarQube static code analysis and came across a report that says using a SafeTokenHandle DangerousGetHandle method call.

I start by declaring a SafeTokenHandle:

```
SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;
var returnValue = Logon(safeTokenHandle);
```

Check it's return value to my logon method.

```
            if (false == returnValue)
            {
                //stuff
            }
```

Use a basic "using" which I log the value of the SafeTokenValue:

```
            using (safeTokenHandle)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Did LogonUser Succeed? " + "Yes");
                Console.WriteLine("Value of Windows NT token: " + safeTokenHandle);
```

Then I have another using which sets a new WindowsItentity using the "DangerousGetHandle" method:

```
                using (var newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
```

Is there any way to go ahead and get that information without using the "DangerousGetHandle" method, or do I just need to accept the risk on this?

[Microsoft Says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.dangerousgethandle?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_DangerousGetHandle):
"DangerousGetHandle method can pose security risks" primarily due to the reference becoming stale which can lead to it accessing sensative information.

It looks like using the [DangerousAddRef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.dangerousaddref?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [DangerousRelease](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.dangerousrelease?view=netframework-4.7.2) is Microsoft's advice, but those also seem to come with risks.  Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: Microsoft themselves use the same API throughout .NET Core, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?q=DangerousGetHandle&unscoped_q=DangerousGetHandle Just pay attention to the pattern in their code to see what measures you need to remedy the risk.

Comment: So in other words, just make sure that the handle doesn't go stale?  My worry is by leaving this in the code it's offering a junior developer a change to grab a stale handle.